# Clear markers from OSM map with openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I have a bunch of Point data that refreshes every few minutes. To render these points, I have created the markers as OpenLayers.Feature.Vector Objects and added them to my Vector layer. The layer gets added to the map object, and I can see the markers when the page loads.

When the data refreshes on my local server, some points from the previous dataset may have disappeared and some new points may have been added. I am just given a large list of points to render every refresh.

Because of this, I need to clear the vector layer of all current markers and then re-render the map with the new dataset.

Also, is there a way to delete specific markers given just a lat,lng? Or is there some way to reference them and delete it from the vectory layer?

How do I clear the vector layer of all markers and how do I delete specific points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this function that works for me:

```
        function clearMapV() {
            features = [];
            features.length = 0;
            vectorLayer.destroyFeatures();
            drawValues(); // call function to re-create markers
        }
```

Or, if you're using markers just use

```
markers.clearMarkers();
```

Where markers is your markers array

Answer (score 3):

Clearing is done with [removeAllFeatures](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.removeAllFeatures):

```
pointLayer.removeAllFeatures();
```

You can remove any that you've stored with [removeFeatures](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.removeFeatures):

```
var aFeature;
//set aFeature somehow 
pointLayer.removeFeature([aFeature]);
```

If you need to find them by location (lat long) I'd look into selecting the features with a [spatial filte](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Filter/Spatial-js.html)r then removing them with removeFeatures.